# What is the type of a vector that contains another vector?

Tags: vector, types, rust

```
struct Tree<T> {
    leaf: Vec<?>
}

fn main() {
    let fuji = Tree { leaf: vec![1, 2, [[3, 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9]] };
}
```

I don't know what I should put in the `Vec<>` so that the code above can run.

Comment: This will not work. For many reasons (the least of which being your actual assignment does not compile anyway). If you remove the `struct` entirely and just try assigning your attempt at a (I think jagged?) vector, you'll see the compiler will not allow it even if you leave the compiler to infer the type for you. For example: `let fuji = vec![1, 2, [[3, 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9]]];`. I would suggest [working your way through the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) to get a better understanding of what Rust and vectors in particular can do in Rust.

Comment: In addition to my comment above: A tree-like structure is _not an easy thing to build_ in Rust. If you're uncomfortable with the general syntax/use of Rust I would definitely advise against trying to implement any sort of tree structure that relies heavily on relationships between nodes. At least until you have a solid grasp of ownership, references and how to use unsafe code in Rust.

Comment: @S Thank U for your advice.It seems that I write Rust in a python way...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead a **tree** is just fine in Rust. A **graph** is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust's `Vec`tor is written `Vec<T>` which means that its every element must be of type `T`. If you need a vector of vectors, this is possible - then it's a `Vec<Vec<T>>` (every element is a `Vec<T>` now).

In your code you wrote:

```
vec![1, 2, [[3, 4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9]]
```

Which is an attempt to create a vector containing integers and a fixed-length (3) array consisting of fixed-length (3) arrays of integers *and* integers. Whew! This is far from homogeneity required by the `Vec` data type.

You could create a vector of vectors like this:

```
let v: Vec<Vec<i32>> = vec![vec![1,2,3], vec![4,5], vec![6]];
```

Since a vector's (unlike an array's) type is not bound to its length, this is a valid `Vec`tor of `Vec`tors which, in turn, are valid because they contain only integers (`i32`).

I recommend going through [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), the best source for basic Rust knowledge.